# How can I get the correct position of each tag in several sentences in the indexed depedency of Stanford Parser?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

Normally I can do it by splitting sentences and tokenize it but there's an example:

"There comes the soldier... I... you must go."

Tagging

There/EX
comes/VBZ
the/DT
soldier/NN
.../:
I./NNP
./.
./.

you/PRP
must/MD
go/VB
./.
Parse

(ROOT
  (S
    (NP (EX There))
    (VP (VBZ comes)
      (NP
        (NP (DT the) (NN soldier))
        (: ...)
        (NP (NNP I.) (. .))))
    (. .)))

(ROOT
  (S
    (NP (PRP you))
    (VP (MD must)
      (VP (VB go)))
    (. .)))

Universal dependencies

expl(comes-2, There-1)
root(ROOT-0, comes-2)
det(soldier-4, the-3)
dobj(comes-2, soldier-4)
dep(soldier-4, I.-6)

nsubj(go-3, you-1)
aux(go-3, must-2)
root(ROOT-0, go-3)

The sentence doesn't stop at the first "...", but at the second one. So easily splitting sentences and count the number of tokens will not help in this case. (Because it will regard this as three sentences.)

Is there any other way that I can know to which parse tree belongs a token? Or a parse tree is which substring of the example? Or directly the position of a tag in this example(three sentences) ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Stanford is interpreting the second ellipsis as a sentence boundary. I'm not quite sure why this ellipsis is seen as a period, but the first one is interpreted correctly.

One hack you could try would be to write a script to tokenize ellipses manually, i.e., separate them from their preceding words. For example, the newly tokenized sentence would be "There comes the soldier ... I ... you must go ." Another approach would be to replace three periods with the unicode ellipsis character.